# Creating ASCII Art Through Putty with C++, but having issues compiling characters

Tags: c++, compilation, ascii, putty

For one of my college assignments, I am to create a simple executable within Putty using C++, which is supposed to output the art that I made using ASCII characters. For some reason the compiler is having issues with the backslashes. As I'm am very new to C++, I am unsure what I need to do in order to resolve the issues so that when I run the file, it just outputs the art that I made.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any backslash character `\` needs to be doubled up `\\`.  That is all.

Backslash is what's called an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) - the parser says "the thing that follows this is handled specially".  Most commonly, that's for a tab `\t` or newline `\n`.

If you want to have a literal backslash, you have to use a double `\\`.

Comment: "An escape character" would be a more correct term.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. edited.